# Three.js release 73 to 76 animation problems

Tags: animation, three.js, hierarchy

I moved from r71 to r76 and discovered the new animation.mixer. So to keep my older json 3D objects librairies working I copied MorphAnimMesh.js Animation.js AnimationHandler.js and KeyFrameAnimation.js (no longer in core) into my javascript lib. But now I get a "data hierarchy undefined" error. Does this mean I have to RE-export all my former 3D json objects from Blender or is there a way the keep these working ? Did I miss to copy some js files ?

Comment: To solve te problem which is to keep my former stuff working I found the following solution : create 2 files JSONLoaderv71.js and Loaderv74.js in which I put the code from three.gs V71 (in core three.js at this time) and of course renamed all THREE...Loader to tHTREE...Loader71. To load I add a slot "version" to them and

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from changes in JSONLoader.js and Loader.js. To solve it so as to keep my former stuff working and nevertheless go for the new animation system in 76 I found the following solution : create 2 files in the vendor js lib :  JSONLoaderv71.js and Loaderv71.js in which I put the code from three.js r71 (in core three.js at this time) and of course renamed all THREE...Loader to THREE...Loader71. Now to load an object I added a private indicator "version" and call ... loader or Loaderv71 according to object version. This looks to me a bit suspicious as a manner to keep backward compatibility but didnt find another solution. Anyway it works !! any opinion on that ?